# Prevent code from running only in visual studio designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a custom control that I have written that does some location checking in the Load event of the control.  This location checking moves the control to a specific location on the screen based on settings in its parent control.  This code works as expected when I compile and run the application.

However, when using the Visual Studio designer, it causes my control to be painted outside of the viewable area and I cannot use the designer.  Is there a flag or attribute I can set to stop that snippet of code from running ONLY when in the Visual Studio designer?

The only work around I have right now is to comment out the code, compile, launch designer, make my changes, then uncomment the code and re-compile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could check the value of [`LicenseManager.UsageMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.licensemanager.usagemode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Runtime)
{
    // Code here won't run in Visual Studio designer
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Visual Studio 2013...any ideas? (Commenting out the entire Load method works).

Comment: Doesn't work in VS2022 either

Answer (score 4):

For those to whom the proposed solution has not worked, I share the following hack:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName != "devenv")
{
    // Code that should not be executed at design time
}
```

What we are doing is getting the name of the process that executed the code. If the name of that process is "devenv", then we do not execute the code.

In the latest versions of Visual Studio, the environment runs in a process named "devenv".

I confirm that this works in VS2015 and VS2017

Yes, I know it's not the most elegant solution, but it works. Yes, I know it's an old query, but there are still some dinosaurs -like me- sticking their hands in this.

Comment: This doesnt work in VS2022

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation, exits from Load method if Design Time is active...

```
this.Load += delegate {
    if(LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) return; //If Design Time -> Exit here 
    // Code here won't run in Visual Studio designer
    // ...
};
```